# search replace the string from number of .txt files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

there are multiple files in directory with extension .txt, .dox, .qcr etc.

i need to list out txt files, search & replace the text from each txt files only.

need to search the $$\d ...where \d stands for the digit 1,2,3.....100.
need to replace with xxx.

please let me know the python script for this .

thanks in advance .

-Shrinivas

`#created following script, it works for single txt files, but it is not working for txt files more than one lies in directory`. 
        -----

```
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

#following code is not working, i expect to list out the files start #with "um_*.txt", open the file & replace the "$$\d" with replaceAll function.

for um_file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    t = open(um_file, 'r')
    replaceAll("t.read","$$\d","xxx")
    t.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
import re
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in file.readlines():  
        try:  
            line = line.replace(re.findall(searchExp,line)[0],replaceExp)
        except:  
            pass
        sys.stdout.write(line)

#following code is not working, i expect to list out the files start #with "um_*.txt", open the file & replace the "$$\d" with replaceAll function.

for um_file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    t = open(um_file, 'r')
    replaceAll(t,"\d+","xxx")
    t.close()
```

Here we are sending file handler to the `replaceAll` function rather than a string.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it is not working for any digit "\d" ...i mean searchExp "$$\d" doesn't get replaced with "xxx", same code is working when i use a digit say 1, then replaceExp will $$1. "\d" is not replacing digit globally.

Comment: @Shrinivas Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

`fileinput.input(...)` is supposed to process a bunch of files, and must be ended with a corresponding `fileinput.close()`. So you can either process all in one single call:

```
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=True):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        dummy = sys.stdout.write(line)      # to avoid a possible output of the size
    fileinput.close()                       # to orderly close everythin


replaceAll(glob.glob('*.txt'), "$$\d","xxx")
```

or consistently close fileinput after processing each file, but it rather ignores the main fileinput feature.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it is not working for any digit "\d" ...i mean searchExp "$$\d" doesn't get replaced with "xxx", same code is working when i use a digit say 1, then replaceExp will $$1. "\d" is not replacing digit globally.

Comment: @Shrinivas: you will need to use the re module if you want to replace regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import os
import re

the_files = [i for i in os.listdir("foldername") if i.endswith("txt")]

for file in the_files:
    new_data = re.sub("\d+", "xxx", open(file).read())
    final_file = open(file, 'w')
    final_file.write(new_data)
    final_file.close()
```